# Prevent adding duplicated values

Tags: entity-framework

In my application I want to assign movie with director. Of course there is no point to store duplicated directors, so somehow I need to prevent adding duplicated rows.

I remember old days having fun with `sql server` and that did the trick:

```
1. Get Director Id
    1a. If director exist return existing director Id
    1b. If director not exist add new and return added director Id
2. Add new Movie with directorId assigned.
```

I am just learning `Entity Framework` and I cant do this in that way. I have to change the way I look at my database as collections. So I am adding `Director` to the `Movie`. I am not sure if I explained that correctly, so I think it would be better to show code:

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Movie firstMovie = new Movie() { Name = "Titanic" };
            Movie secondMovie = new Movie() { Name = "Pulp Fiction" };
            Movie thirdMovie = new Movie() { Name = "Matrix" };

            Director director = new Director() { Name = "Warner Bros" };

            firstMovie.Director = director;
            secondMovie.Director = director;
            thirdMovie.Director = director;

            Db.AddMovie(firstMovie);
            Db.AddMovie(secondMovie);
            Db.AddMovie(thirdMovie);
        }
    }

    public class Movie {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int DirectorId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DirectorId")]
        public virtual Director Director { get; set; }
    }

    public class Director {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

        public Director() {
            Movies = new List<Movie>();
        }
    }

    public class Db {
        public static int AddMovie(Movie movie) {
            using (var context = new MovieContext()) {
                    context.Movies.Add(movie);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return movie.Id;
                }
            }
    }

    public class MovieContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Director> Directories { get; set; }
    }
```

And the thing is after that I have 3x the same `Director` in my database. I expected to have only 1. But how can I archieve that? How can I prevent adding the same `Directories`? I mean I cant check if there is already `directory` with the same name, because I am not adding them manually. `Entity Framework` is adding new `Directory`, not me. So, what can I do with it?

What I've manged is to add `directorId` and let entity framework assign with proper object. This is how I've changed `main`:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
            Movie firstMovie = new Movie() { Name = "Titanic" };
            Movie secondMovie = new Movie() { Name = "Pulp Fiction" };
            Movie thirdMovie = new Movie() { Name = "Matrix" };

            Director director = Db.GetDirector("Warner Bros");

            firstMovie.DirectorId = director.Id;
            secondMovie.DirectorId = director.Id;
            thirdMovie.DirectorId = director.Id;

            Db.AddMovie(firstMovie);
            Db.AddMovie(secondMovie);
            Db.AddMovie(thirdMovie);
        }
```

And that's my new method which will return `Director` (and add if it is necessary)

```
public static Director GetDirector(string directorName) {
            using (var context = new MovieContext()) {
                if (context.Directories.Any(x => x.Name == directorName))
                    return context.Directories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == directorName);
                else {
                    Director newDirector = new Director() { Name = directorName };
                    context.Directories.Add(newDirector);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return newDirector;
                }
            }
        }
```

So it is the best way to do it? I am not sure if adding new `Director` is proper coded. Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way you're doing it will always result in a new director row for each reference to the same director object. Why? Because they are being added in three different contexts.

EF only tracks objects through `DbContext`. It will (sadly, maybe) not attempt to glean anything about the state of an object within a graph from properties of that object.  So, the second time you save a `Movie` with the same director as the first, EF simply sees that it doesn't know anything about that `Director` and proceeds to add it to the graph as a new object as well. When `SaveChanges()` is called, it is duly added to the database.

You can watch this happen by looking at the `DbEntry` for the `Director` reference before `SaveChanges()`, and you'll also see `Director.Id` change each time as well.

There are a few strategies you can use to mitigate this behavior:

1. Add everything in a single context.
2. Add the director, then for each movie, only set `DirectorId` from `Director.Id`.
3. Add the director, the for each movie manually set the entry-state for the director object to "unchanged".
4. In the context, first do a `context.Directors.Find(movie.Director.Id);` to make sure the director is already in the context before adding the movie.

Comment: Thanks. Second strategy seems to be the most sensible for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could go the way from the other side.
Just add the `Movie` objects to your one `Director` object's collection. After that save the `Director` object to database and it should work like you want.

Only as sample code:

```
Movie firstMovie = new Movie { Name = "Titanic" };
Movie secondMovie = new Movie { Name = "Pulp Fiction" };
Movie thirdMovie = new Movie { Name = "Matrix" };

// here you should take one from data context or create it, if it does not exist
Director director = new Director { Name = "Warner Bros" }; 

director.Movies.Add(firstMovie);
director.Movies.Add(secondMovie);
director.Movies.Add(thirdMovie);

// add new or update director with new movies
Db.AddOrUpdateDirector(director);
```

And of course, instead of just create a new one you should check if the directory already exist in datacontext and use that one.

Answer (score 0):

> I have 3x the same Director in my database.

I think you have three different directors, they will have a different ID.

If you want to have just one director you need to let know to the DataContext about him. Maybe you can add a method AddDirector and add the director to the database before to use it.
Then when you do:

```
firstMovie.Director = director;
secondMovie.Director = director;
thirdMovie.Director = director;
```

The DataContext will know the director, and you will have the same for your three movies.

> I mean I cant check if there is already directory with the same name,
>   because I am not adding them manually. Entity Framework is adding new
>   Directory, not me. So, what can I do with it?

For Entity Framework two directors with no ID value are two different directors. **The only way to let it know that you want to use the same director is using a director with an ID value.**
So you can:
- Create your director with a name and an id new Director { Id = 1, Name="Warner Bros" }
- Use a director that exist in the database (Entity Framework know about him, he has an ID)

Comment: I cant do that. When I add new director and assign this director to all movies at the end I am getting 3x directors in database. What is working is to add new director, but assign by id: `firstMovie.Director.Id = director.Id;`. My questions is - why I cant assign by reference?